# How to use cgroups to limit all processes except whitelist to a single CPU?

Tags: cgroups, resources, cpu-usage

There is a [guide to cgroups from Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Resource_Management_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Resource_Management_Guide-en-US.pdf) which is maybe sort of kind of helpful (but doesn't answer this question).

I know how to limit a specific process to a specific CPU, during the command to start that process, by:

First, putting the following* in `/etc/cgconfig.conf`:

```
mount {
  cpuset =  /cgroup/cpuset;
  cpu =     /cgroup/cpu;
  cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
  memory =  /cgroup/memory;
  devices = /cgroup/devices;
  freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
  net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
  blkio =   /cgroup/blkio;
}

group cpu0only {
  cpuset {
    cpuset.cpus = 0;
    cpuset.mems = 0;
  }
}
```

And then start a process and assign it specifically to that cgroup by using:

```
cgexec -g cpuset:cpu0only myprocessname
```

I can limit all instances of a specific process name automatically by (I *think* this is correct) putting the following in `/etc/cgrules.conf`:

```
# user:process  controller  destination
*:myprocessname cpuset      cpu0only
```

My question is: How can I do the *reverse*?

In other words, **How can I assign *all* processes except for a specific set of whitelisted processes *and their children* to a restricted cgroup?**

---

Based on what I have studied, but haven't tested, I *believe* that a *partial* solution would be:

Add an "unrestricted" cgroup:

```
group anycpu {
  cpuset {
    cpuset.cpus = 0-31;
    cpuset.mems = 0;  # Not sure about this param but it seems to be required
  }
}
```

Assign my process explicitly to the unrestricted group, and everything else to the restricted group:

```
# user:process  controller  destination
*:myprocessname cpuset      anycpu
*               cpuset      cpu0only
```

However, the caveat on this seems to be (from reading the docs, not from testing, so grain of salt) that the children of `myprocessname` will be reassigned to the restricted `cpu0only` cgroup.

A possible alternative approach would be to create a user to run `myprocessname` and have all of *that user's* processes unrestricted, and everything else restricted.  However, in my actual use case, the process needs to be run by root, and there are other processes that also must be run by root which *should* be restricted.

How can I accomplish this with cgroups?

---

**If this is not possible with cgroups** (which I now suspect is the case), **are my ideas of partial solutions correct and will they work as I think?**

<sub>*Disclaimer: This is probably not a minimal code example;I don't understand *all* the parts so I don't know which are not necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 36, accepted):

UPDATE: Note that the answer below applies to RHEL 6.  In RHEL 7, most cgroups are managed by systemd, and libcgroup is deprecated.

---

Since posting this question I have studied the entire guide that I linked to above, as well as the majority of the [cgroups.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) documentation and [cpusets.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cpusets.txt).  I now know more than I ever expected to learn about cgroups, so I'll answer my own question here.

There are multiple approaches you can take.  Our company's contact at Red Hat (a Technical Architect) recommended against a blanket restriction of all processes in preference to a more declarative approach—restricting only the processes we specifically wanted restricted.  The reason for this, according to his statements on the subject, is that it is possible for system calls to depend on user space code (such as LVM processes) which if restricted could slow the system down—the opposite of the intended effect.  So I ended up restricting several specifically-named processes and leaving everything else alone.

Additionally, I want to mention some **cgroup basic data** that I was missing when I posted my question.

---

**Cgroups do *not* depend on `libcgroup` being installed.**  However, that is a set of tools for automatically handling cgroup configuration and process assignments to cgroups and can be very helpful.

I found that the libcgroup tools can also be misleading, because the libcgroup package is built on its *own* set of abstractions and assumptions about your use of cgroups, which are slightly different than the actual kernel level implementation of cgroups.  (I can put examples but it would take some work; comment if you're interested.)

Therefore, before using libcgroup tools (such as `/etc/cgconfig.conf`, `/etc/cgrules.conf`, `cgexec`, `cgcreate`, `cgclassify`, etc.) I *highly* recommend getting very familiar with the `/cgroup` virtual filesystem itself, and manually creating cgroups, cgroup hierarchies (including hierarchies with multiple subsystems attached, which libcgroup sneakily and leakily abstracts away), reassigning processes to different cgroups by running `echo $the_pid > /cgroup/some_cgroup_hierarchy/a_cgroup_within_that_hierarchy/tasks`, and other seemingly magical tasks that `libcgroup` performs under the hood.

---

Another basic concept I was missing was that if the `/cgroup` virtual filesystem is mounted on your system at all (or more accurately, if any of the cgroup subsystems aka "controllers" are mounted at all), then *every* process on your entire system *is in* a cgroup.  **There is no such thing as "some processes are in a cgroup and some aren't".**

There is what is called the *root* cgroup for a given hierarchy, which owns *all* the system's resources for the attached subsystems.  For example a cgroup hierarchy that has the cpuset and blkio subsystems attached, would have a root cgroup which would own *all* the cpus on the system and all the blkio on the system, and could share some of those resources with *child* cgroups.  You can't restrict the root cgroup because it owns *all* your system's resources, so restricting it wouldn't even make sense.

---

Some other simple data I was missing about libcgroup:

If you use `/etc/cgconfig.conf`, you should ensure that `chkconfig --list cgconfig` shows that `cgconfig` is set to run at system boot.

If you change `/etc/cgconfig.conf`, you need to run `service cgconfig restart` to load in the changes.  (And problems with stopping the service or running `cgclear` are very common when fooling around testing.  For debugging I recommend, for example, `lsof /cgroup/cpuset`, if `cpuset` is the name of the cgroup hierarchy you are using.)

If you want to use `/etc/cgrules.conf`, you need to ensure the "cgroup rules engine daemon" (`cgrulesengd`) is running: `service cgred start` and `chkconfig cgred on`.  (And you should be aware of a possible but unlikely race condition regarding this service, as described in the [Red Hat Resource Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Resource_Management_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Resource_Management_Guide-en-US.pdf) in section 2.8.1 at the bottom of the page.)

If you want to fool around manually and set up your cgroups using the virtual filesystem (which I recommend for first use), you can do so and then create a `cgconfig.conf` file to mirror your setup by using `cgsnapshot` with its various options.

---

And finally, the key piece of info I was missing when I wrote the following:

> However, the caveat on this seems to be...that the children of myprocessname will be reassigned to the restricted cpu0only cgroup.

I was correct, but there is an option I was unaware of.

`cgexec` is the command to start a process/run a command and assign it to a cgroup.

`cgclassify` is the command to assign an already running process to a cgroup.

Both of these will also prevent `cgred` (`cgrulesengd`) from reassigning the specified process to a different cgroup based on `/etc/cgrules.conf`.

**Both `cgexec` and `cgclassify` support the `--sticky` flag, which *additionally* prevents `cgred` from reassigning *child* processes based on `/etc/cgrules.conf`.**

---

So, **the answer to the question as I wrote it** (though not the setup I ended up implementing, because of the advice from our Red Hat Technical Architect mentioned above) is:

Make the `cpu0only` and `anycpu` cgroup as described in my question.  (Ensure `cgconfig` is set to run at boot.)

Make the `*  cpuset   cpu0only` rule as described in my question.  (And ensure `cgred` is set to run at boot.)

Start any processes I want *unrestricted* with: `cgexec -g cpuset:anycpu --sticky myprocessname`.

Those processes will be unrestricted, and all their child processes will be unrestricted as well.  **Everything else on the system** will be restricted to CPU 0 (once you reboot, since `cgred` doesn't apply cgrules to already running processes unless they change their EUID).  This is not completely advisable, but that was what I initially requested and it *can* be done with cgroups.

Comment: wow. cool. how did this have 0 votes?

Comment: @mikeserv, thanks.  :)  Answer to your question: check the dates; I just wrote this answer yesterday.

Comment: i saw that.  but it was 24 hours ago. probably its cause its long. the good stuff can sometimes get overlooked like that. and anyway, the answers with a *lot* of votes really soon are very rarely the good ones - information can't be that useful if so many people already know it is. this is one of the good ones, though. cgroups are friggin mysterious.