# What is the meaning of "same CPU-group" in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device

What is the meaning of [`complete on same CPU-group`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L489)?
I seen two line code:

```
#define QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_COMP    9   /* complete on same CPU-group */
#define QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_FORCE  18   /* force complete on same CPU */
```

`CPU-group` is equal to `CPU`?
What is difference between `force complete` and `non-force complete`?

Comment: Some context would help.

Comment: Sounds like [cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247209/135943).

Comment: @Wildcard On [link 499](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L499) have similar code comment,so that meaning is ` CPU == CPU-groups ` ?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  I'm not a kernel developer.  I recommend reading up on it in a good book; I've heard good things about [Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/).

Answer (score 0):

So here is the difference

```
#define QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_COMP    9   /* complete on same CPU-group */
#define QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_FORCE  18   /* force complete on same CPU */
```

Now same CPU group can be defined as

- either cpu's are under same cluster ( say cpu groups) then preferred cpu for completion will be 1st cpu of that cluster else any online cpu of that cluster.
  This was mosty true for kernel < 5.9.
  For example if out of cpu[0-8], if all cpu's under cpu[0-4] are of same type, then it will be called same cpu group.
- Or all cpu's sharing same L3 cache. then those will be part of same cpu group.
  For example if your system having cpu0-8 and they same same L3 level cache, then it will be termed as same group cpu.

Now coming on 2nd query
So with **QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_COMP**, request will be completed on a cpu which falls under same cpu group. Let's say interrupt received on cpu3 for a request which was originated from cpu0, then since cpu0 and cpu 3 are under same group, then same cpu where irq was completed, softirq / request completion would be triggered,

But you enforce to complete by choosing **QUEUE_FLAG_SAME_FORCE**, after top half handling, bottom half will be force to same cpu, from where request was originated. Say cpu 3 in above example. Then request will be completed on cpu3. So it helps by pushing most of the block layer and SCSI midlayer completion work back to the submitting CPU say cpu3 (via an IPI).