# cgroup virtual file system is read only for root, when root has write privileges?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kernel, cgroups, sysfs

As the title of my question suggests, I am trying to edit the properties of my cgroup virtual file system - create new directories, edit the resource limits in certain files, etc - but any write action I take returns:

```
cannot do action in 'fs/cgroup/': Read-only file system
```

Even after running `chmod 755` as root, the result is the same. Confirming root has write access, I check the output of `ls -al` and see:

```
drwx-xr-x 15 root root 380 Mar 31 09:28 cgroup
```

When I read online examples, editing/creating files within `/cgroup/` is an initial step covered, with no mention of issues performing this task. Seeking a solution, I thought possibly the issue is because the cgroup is mounted. That, because all system processes are listed within it, I am not allowed to edit its contents.

Following this hunch, I attempted to unmount the cgroup:

```
umount cgroup
```

Which returned the usual:

```
target is busy.
```

To my knowledge, a root user attempting to write to a directory owned by root, with root write permissions, should be allowed - what am I not seeing ?

I have been reading various man pages, the online kernel site, and several helpful stack excahnge posts such as [How to use cgroups to limit all processes except whitelist to a single CPU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247209/how-to-use-cgroups-to-limit-all-processes-except-whitelist-to-a-single-cpu). Nowhere am I able to find reference to the issue I am encountering.

Does anyone with more experience have a light they could shine in my direction ?

### Update

The cgroups listed at mounted, shown by running `grep cgroup /proc/mounts`, are:

```
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
```

### Specific Command Outputs

Specific commands I have tried to write with, and their outputs, are:

1. In /sys/fs/cgroup/unified, with `ls` showing the file `cgroup.subtree_control` exists:

```
echo "+cpu +memory" > cgroup.subtree_control
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

2. Attempting to write desired controllers direct to `cgroup.controllers` gives:

```
echo "cpu" > cgroup.controllers
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

3. If I try to write to the file `cgroup.subtree_control` via `nano`, the `nano` client opens the file but displays at the screen bottom:

```
[ Error writing lock file ./.cgroup.subtree_control.swp: Permission denied ]
```

4. Creating a file on `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified` is denied:

```
touch file
touch: cannot touch 'file': Permission denied
```

5. Creating a directory on `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified` is allowed:

```
mkdir newDir
```

And is populated with cgroup files:

```
ls newDir
cgroup.controllers  cgroup.max.descendants  cgroup.threads  io.pressure
cgroup.events       cgroup.procs            cgroup.type     memory.pressure
cgroup.freeze       cgroup.stat             cpu.pressure
cgroup.max.depth    cgroup.subtree_control  cpu.stat
```

But I once again cannot create (via `touch`) or edit:

```
echo cpu > cgroup.controllers
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

6. I expected the root `cgroup.controller` file to contain some controllers, however this is not the case:

```
cat cgroup.controllers
# returns an empty string
```

Perhaps this is a hint toward the issue ?

My expectations as the output of these commands are based on the kernel documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html

### Update 2

After unmounting cgroup version 1 filesystems with:

```
mount -t cgroup | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | xargs sudo umount
```

The root `unified` directory file named `cgroup.controllers` now does contain controller names:

```
cat cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu io rdma
```

And I may write these names to the `cgroup.subtree_controller`:

```
echo -n "+cpuset +cpu +io +rdma " >> cgroup.subtree_controller
```

But attempting to write a new controller, for example the `memory` controller, won't work:

```
echo -n "+memory " > cgroup.subtree_controller
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

### System Specs

-OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

-Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-174-generic

Comment: Add to your answer:  What is the output of `grep cgroup /proc/mounts ` and exactly what file did you try to modify that it gave you `Read-only file system`